# get tooltip on the left of mouse

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to implement a simple tooltip on my website. It works fine, showing the tooltip to the right of the cursor, but now I'm trying to get the same effect only positioned to the left of the cursor. How do I achieve this?

Here is my code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3r5aq/

Probably a novice thing to ask, but I can't seem to figure this one out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the width of the tooltip.  Obviously if you have multiple on the page, you will need to update the selector.

```
.mousemove(function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX - 5 - $(".tooltip").width(); //Get X coordinates
            var mousey = e.pageY;      //Get Y coordinates
            $('.tooltip')
            .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex})
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3r5aq/18/

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following:

```
var mousex;
var left = e.pageX - $('.tooltip').width() - 20;
if(left > 0)            
    mousex = left;
else
    mousex = 0;
```

This way, the tooltip doesn't run outside of the visible area if the link is too far left on the page.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3r5aq/22/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to go to the left by simply modifying the x value according to the size of the tooltip:

```
var mousex = e.pageX - $('.tooltip').width() - 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Tooltip only Text
        $('.nextTooltip').hover(function(){
                // Hover over code
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                .text(title)
                .appendTo('body')
                .fadeIn('fast');
        }, function() {
                // Hover out code
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                $('.tooltip').remove();
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
                var mousex = e.pageX;      //Get X coordinates
                var mousey = e.pageY;      //Get Y coordinates
                $('.tooltip').each(function(ix, item) {
                    $(item).css({
                        top: mousey,
                        left: mousex - $(item).width() - 20
                    });
                });
        });
});​
```